# Center of Mass and Concurrency of Lines

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

Given points $v_1$, $v_2$,...,$v_p \in \mathbb{R^n}$ and corresponding "masses" $m_1, m_2...,m_p>0,$ the center of mass can be defined as:

$$\frac{m_1v_1+m_2v_2+...+m_pv_p}{m_1+m_2+...+m_p}$$

Prove that if $p \geq 3$, then the $p$ lines, say $L_1, L_2,..., L_p$ [where $L_i$ joins $v_i$ ($1 \leq i \leq p)$ to the center of mass of the other $p-1$ points], all meet at the center of mass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

By symmetry, you only have to show that the line joining $\ v_p\ $ to the centre of mass of the points $\ v_1,v_2,\dots,v_{p-1}\ $ passes through the centre of mass of all the points.  The line joining $\ v_p\ $ to the centre of mass of the points $\ v_1,v_2,\dots,v_{p-1}\ $ has parametric equation
$$
v=t\left(\frac{\sum_\limits{i=1}^{p-1}m_iv_i}{\sum_\limits{i=1}^{p-1}m_i}\right)+(1-t)v_p
$$
If $\ 
 t=\frac{\sum_\limits{i=1}^{p-1}m_i}{\sum_\limits{i=1}^pm_i}\  ,$ what is the corresponding point $\ v\ $ on this line?

Comment: In fact, it is a consequence of the so-called "barycentric associativity".